# Change parent label background when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css

I want the selection (`:checked`) to have a different background colour.

Here my example code:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background: gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label + [type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="poll">
  <label class="a"><input type="checkbox" /> Yes</label>
  <label class="a"><input type="checkbox" /> No</label>
</div>
```

My question is related to: [Design survey form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75144312/design-survey-form/75144606?noredirect=1#75144695)

Also take into account the situation where the input is preset in the DOM, but hidden, so the label is still clickable and toggles it.

Comment: This question was closed as duplicate to "similar" questions but they are unhelpful for the situation of the OP. This is a specific case for `input` of type `checkbox`. I've re-opened it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You can use the [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo selector for that:

[image]

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background: gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

label:has([type="checkbox"]:checked) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="poll">
  <label class="a"><input type="checkbox" /> Yes</label>
  <label class="a"><input type="checkbox" /> No</label>
</div>
```

#### If you need browser backward-compatibility support, here's a trick:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background: gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden; /* Important so the outline won't overflow */
  user-select: none;
}

label :checked {
  outline: 9999px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="poll">
  <label><input type="checkbox" /> Yes</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" /> No</label>
</div>
```

---

#### OP asked me in the comments for a solution tailored for a hidden checkbox.

All that is needed is to use the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute on the input. 
Never use CSS `display: none` to not render an input element.
It is preferable to use the [designated attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden).

Note that this also has a bug in Firefox. Below is a Firefox-hack to overcome it.

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background: gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

label:has([type="checkbox"]:checked) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="poll">
  <label><input type="checkbox" hidden /> Yes</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" hidden /> No</label>
</div>
```

#### Firefox-supported solution:

Extract each `input` to be above the `label` element, and use a unique `id` attribute on each `input` element, and a matching `for` attribute on each `label`:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  background: gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

:checked + label {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="poll">
  <input type="checkbox" id='poll-1' hidden/>
  <label for='poll-1'>Yes</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id='poll-2' hidden/>
  <label for='poll-2'>No</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I view minutes i will accept your answer. Have a nice day ..

Comment: Your example codes don't seem to work on Firefox (v108). They do work on Chrome.

Comment: @Martin - sorry, forgot some people use Firefox. will take a look!

Comment: @vsync Firefox 108 requires the config setting `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` to be enabled `true`. I expect future versions will have it set by default. `:-)`

Comment: neither work in FX https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: ok even with that setting set and firefox restarted, the `:has` selector on your code still isn't setting the background to yellow `:-(` .. Sorry

Comment: Here is something interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145504/style-a-checkbox-in-firefox-remove-check-and-border

Comment: Seems like a Firefox new bug. I will report them

Comment: Fixed for Firefox - replaced malfunctioned `box-shadow` with `outline` and opened a [bug for Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1810708)

Comment: @vsync Thank you for your time! Your second solution will work on Firefox **but** for me doesnt work because i set `input {display: none}`. And then it dont work. Maybe you have an idea? Or i will use javascript and set a class.

Comment: @vsync yep that works on my firefox now. Cheers!

Comment: @MaxPattern - You should have mentioned you are setting `display:none` in your question. I will update my answer now with another solution for such case.

Comment: Thank you very much @vsync! It works for safari too. I learned something today. that is great. Merci